# What are the risks of using 301?

Tags: seo

We want to migrate from CMS to own system.

Page addresses in CMS and own system are different. We want to use 301 redirect to all website's pages.

The output HTML of CMS and own system have some few differences:

- OpenGraph semantic
- No javascript generated by CMS

Should we be afraid the failing of search traffic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

If done properly, the 301 is the way to go when the url is changed permanently. The most common mistake our clients do is to change the URL of a page and never redirects the old page's url to the updated location. This causes 404 pages.

My advice is to structure everything. Start with generating a file containing all current URL of the website. Then use an excel file or google sheet and pages those in. Right next to that column add another one - this is the column where you decide what you should do with each URL (either keep, remove/kill, combine it another page or change the URL).

Since you want to change the CMS, I am not sure how your have structured your pages right now and how they are indexed, BUT whatever you do, make sure that if ***anything*** in the URL has been changed, use a 301 to permanently redirect the old URL to the new location. Otherwise if that page receives some traffic, you will lose the traffic as the visitors would land on 404 (page not found) page.

Go through the URL list, one by one and determine what will happen with that page/url.